# How to capture packets from all wifi channels at once?

Tags: wireless, wireshark

I'm doing a project in which I need to capture a live feed of all wireless networks available around a given device. I was hoping to go a step further and capture all packets as well using Wireshark, but from what I've seen, Wireshark will require you to capture only on a particular network or at least on a particular wireless channel.

My questions are: a) is there a way for Wireshark to capture *all* wireless traffic on all channels and networks at once? And, if not, then, b) is there a way to at least capture (probably using some other tool) a live feed of all wireless networks available?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.Because of the design of physical radio interface.

### As you can not connect to all the channels (more than one) at a time, same applies while capturing the WLAN traffic. In capture scenario you are merely turning your radio interface from access mode to monitor mode and hence it can monitor only on one channel at a time.

To do this, you need to build a specialized capture device.

### If i were you, i would try with Raspberry Pi's, setting up a linux distro which lets you install air-mon and try.

All the best!!!!

Comment: OK thanks! If you add an answer to question (b), I'll mark this the correct answer.